# No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I know that there are other questions in stackoverflow talking about similar issue but here the problem is different. I am working on a spring boot project to create a service. The service exposes some APIs, also it retrieves data from another SOAP based service. I added following code to my main method

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl");
```

and the application is working just fine when I run it from eclipse and access exposed APIs. However, when I access APIs by executing FatJAR created using maven then I get following error

```
ERROR [http-nio-8090-exec-7] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getClassLoader(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getClassLoader(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getClassLoader(LogFactoryImpl.java:447)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.initDiagnostics(LogFactoryImpl.java:476)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.<init>(LogFactoryImpl.java:95)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:590)
        at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.newInstance(ClassUtils.java:153)
```

**If I remove the following line from my main method and create FatJAR**

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl");
```

and start the service from fatJAR and access APIs then it runs fine. But running application form eclipse and accessing APIs gives the following error

```
ERROR[0;39m [[34mhttp-nio-8090-exec-4[0;39m] [33morg.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog[0;39m: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.find(DiscoverClass.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.newInstance(DiscoverClass.java:579)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:418)
    at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:378)
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
```

**following is the snippet from my POM.**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

The project builds, install, deploy without any issue. The error occurs only when I access the API after running the application. I search other resources they all are saying that there might be some Logging JAR conflict so I removed some dependency and added different dependencies but all the time it ends up in error either in eclipse or FatJAR.

Any help or reference for other resources are welcome.